# Existence of unbounded continuous function on a set not closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is not closed. How can we show that there is a continuous function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is not bounded?

Comment: I just gave you a proof in chat!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is there any way you can give the basics of the proof you provided via chat?

Comment: @user66807: As I recall, it was essentially identical to the one that Panda later gave here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I tried to understand what was said, but I didn't understand what $d(x,p)$ was and I was wondering what the thought process was of coming up with such a function. Was it just an already known thing, or is there a way to arrive at it?

Comment: @user66807: $d(x,p)$ is just the distance from $x$ to $p$. The idea is that since $A$ is not closed, it has a limit point $p$ that is not in $A$. The function $g:A\to\Bbb R$ defined by $g(x)=d(x,p)$ is continuous, and since $p\notin A$, $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in A$. Thus, $f(x)=\frac1{g(x)}$ is well-defined and also continuous. Finally, take any sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of points of $A$ converging to $p$; there is one, since $p$ is a limit point of $A$. Then $g(x_n)\to 0$, so $f(x_n)\to\infty$, and $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is not closed, therefore there exists a limit point $p$ of $A$, for which $p \notin A$. The function $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{d(x,p)}$$ does the trick.